# Get term by custom term meta and taxonomy

Tags: wp-query, tax-query, term-meta

How to get term by custom term meta and taxonomy or how to filter `tax_query` by term meta instead `slug`/`id`?

```
function custom_pre_get_posts($query)
{
    global $wp_query;

    if ( !is_admin() && is_shop() && $query->is_main_query()  && is_post_type_archive( "product" )) 
    {
        $term = ???get_term_by_meta_and_taxonomy???('custom_meta_term','my_taxonomy');
        $t_id = $term['term_id'];
        $tax_query = array
        (
            array
            (
                'taxonomy' => 'my_taxoomy',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $t_id
            )
        );
        $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts' );
```

Answer (score 22):

Try This:

```
$args = array(
'hide_empty' => false, // also retrieve terms which are not used yet
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
       'key'       => 'feature-group',
       'value'     => 'kitchen',
       'compare'   => 'LIKE'
    )
),
'taxonomy'  => 'category',
);
$terms = get_terms( $args );
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as this is the best practice for this case.

Comment: Agreed, I've confirmed and this accomplishes retrieving a term via a term meta key and value.  Ensure hide_empty is set to false if you're term has no associated posts yet.

Comment: Also think this should be the accepted answer for this case

Answer (score 3):

Building on the answer from [ilgıt-yıldırım](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/126572/ilg%C4%B1t-y%C4%B1ld%C4%B1r%C4%B1m) above, both the `get_term_meta` statement and `$key == 'meta_value'` statements need to contain `$term>term_id`.

Here's a complete example including the custom `$wp_query` request:

```
$term_args = array( 'taxonomy' => 'your-taxonomy' );
$terms = get_terms( $term_args );

$term_ids = array();

foreach( $terms as $term ) {
    $key = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'term-meta-key', true );

    if( $key == 'term-meta-value' ) {
        // push the ID into the array
        $term_ids[] = $term->term_id;
    }
}

// Loop Args
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'posts',
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'your-taxonomy',
        'terms'    => $term_ids,
         ),
    ),
);

// The Query
$featured = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to loop through each of the terms in your main query conditional. Assuming there will likely be more than one term with the custom data, you'll then need to pass an array of IDs into your tax query.

For example, looping through each term to check for custom meta:

```
$term_args = array(
    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy_name,
    );


$terms = get_terms( $term_args );

$term_ids = array();

foreach( $terms as $term ) {
    $key = get_term_meta( $term->ID, 'meta_key', true );
    if( $key == 'meta_value' ) {
        // push the ID into the array
        $term_ids[] = $term->ID;
    }
}
```

Then you end up with the variable $term_ids which contains an array of the term IDs you're looking for. You can pass that to your tax query.

Comment: `get_term_meta( $term->ID, 'meta_key', true );` should be `get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'meta_key', true );` as `$term` would be `WP_Term` object.

Comment: For any new comers, this is very inefficient and would be considered a last option. See the `meta_query` answer as this is the better approach.